# Postgres where clause compare timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where column is of datatype `timestamp`

Which contains records multiple records for a day 
I want to select all rows corresponding to day

How do I do it?

Answer (score 232, accepted):

<sup>Assuming you actually mean `timestamp` because there is no `datetime` in Postgres</sup>

Cast the timestamp column to a date, that will remove the time part:

```
select *
from the_table
where the_timestamp_column::date = date '2015-07-15';
```

This will return all rows from July, 15th.

Note that the above will **not** use an index on `the_timestamp_column`. If performance is critical, you need to either create an index on that expression or use a range condition:

```
select *
from the_table
where the_timestamp_column >= timestamp '2015-07-15 00:00:00'
  and the_timestamp_column < timestamp '2015-07-16 00:00:00';
```

Comment: wish i had read the second part before submitting the first style query to a large table...

Comment: You can compare timestamps directly with date strings. Postgres is smart enough to do the casting for you.

`where the_timestamp_column >= '2015-07-15' and the_timestamp_column < '2015-07-16'`

Comment: select *
from the_table
where the_timestamp_column::date = date '2015-07-15'; worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: the casting in date '2015-07-15' is not required!

Comment: you can use DATE(the_timestamp_column)
select * from the_table where DATE(the_timestamp_column) = date '2015-07-15';

Comment: @İbrahimYANIK: which is the same as my first condition/query