# shell script passing into psql?

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell

i am new in shell script command.
i want to passing value from Parameter into Psql script.
i already use this link as my example but no good.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/how-to-execute-postgresql-commands-inside-unix-shell-scripts/

here my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
dbname="XXX"
dbuser="YYY"
dbport="8888"
dbip="xx.xx.xx.xx"
min_tgl= cut -d"," -f1 /SOURCE/tanggaldata
max_tgl= cut -d"," -f2 /SOURCE/tanggaldata
echo $min_tgl
echo $max_tgl
psql -d $dbname -U $dbuser -h $dbip -p $dbport -t << EOF > $path"AGNT_COUNT.TXT"
SELECT TRIM(COUNT(1)) as MICROSEC FROM stg.agntpf__ct where attu_timestamp > ='$min_tgl' AND attu_timestamp <= '$max_tgl';
EOF
```

for the @min_tgl and $max_tgl already has result
and i already change '' into `"''"` or `'""'` but no luck.
here the result error from query on top
[image]

here the result on screen
[image]

to answer comment @mark 
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have a space in the middle of `>=`

Comment: thank @mark Setchell but no luck.

Comment: Try replacing `attu_timestamp` with `attu_timestamp::date` in both places it occurs.

Comment: Thank mark but still no luck. see picture above. Thank You

Comment: You may need an extra `timestamp` before your timestamp value https://stackoverflow.com/a/31433748/2836621

Comment: whats's the utput of `cut -d"," -f1 /SOURCE/tanggaldata`?..

Comment: 2017-08-04 08:00:00 the value is changing because the somebody running the query  and change into 2017-08-04 12:00:00. but the variable running on psql cannot read it. i cannot guess what wrong with my variable ?

Comment: Try something simple like: `a=(psql -Atc 'select 1;');echo $a` to start. You may be getting headers in the way or something.